# Custom font not being set, iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, custom-font

I am trying to change the font of a label to "Museo_500italic.otf"  I have imported it to my project and added it to the p-list, but it doesn't recognize the font.  I've done it with other fonts, a couple of months ago, but this one for some reason isn't working.  Am I forgetting something?

This is what I've got:

[image: top row]

[image: Third one from bottom]

This gives me Museo-500 for a font:

`self.createAccTxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-500" size:17.5];`

These give me the default font:

`self.createAccTxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-500Italic" size:17.5];`
`self.createAccTxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-500_Italic" size:17.5];`
`self.createAccTxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-500-Italic" size:17.5];`
`self.createAccTxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-500italic" size:17.5];`
`self.createAccTxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-500_italic" size:17.5];`
`self.createAccTxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-500-italic" size:17.5];`

Comment: In your fontWithName: calls, the string with the font name needs to be precisely as it's written in the "Font Book" app, as part of OSX.

Comment: You are the man. That was my problem, I had changed the name when I added it to my project.  I just added it again, without changing the name and then adjusted the p-list and the name of the font when I set it to the label.

Comment: I'd best post as an answer to wrap this up :) Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `fontWithName:` calls, the string with the font name needs to be precisely as it's written in the "Font Book" app, as part of OSX.