# "Swanky and Moo Moo" font is not working in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uifont

I am using "Swanky and Moo Moo" in my application, but it displays the font style as like of system font..

Here my code....

```
myLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Swanky and Moo Moo" size:16];
```

I have refer the following links..

[iOS: How can i set a non system font family, style, size of UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747325/ios-how-can-i-set-a-non-system-font-family-style-size-of-uilabel)

http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635

But thats are not useful for me.......

Can antone tell me that how to set the `myLabel` font style as **Swanky and Moo Moo**??

Comment: Dont use file name of that font, open font in your Mac in font book and write same name present in font book

Comment: Please take a look it will help http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-custom-font-in-xcode.html

Comment: @Prateek in font book, the font name is like  Swanky and Moo Moo only

Comment: Please check this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922705/custom-font-not-being-set-iphone/13923089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add your custom font files into your project using XCode as
   resources.
2. Add key font provided by application to your info plist.(array key)
3. For each font add the full font file name along with extension as
   item into the key.
4. Now you can use the font as   UIFont *customFont = [UIFont
   fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
5. The catch   the font name is not the font file name every time.....
6. you can install the font file to check its font name....use that
   name and you are sorted....
   **Note:-  If it still dosent work go to build phases ->copy bundle resources and add all your font files**

Comment: ty `build phases ->copy bundle resources and add all your font files` this will helps me.....

Comment: what's the name of the font you use finally? Swanky and Moo Moo? I am curious if you need to use the Full name or Postcript name.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the solution you will find on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application) you need to make sure you provide the exact name you will see for the `Full name` or '`Postscript name` tag in `fontbook`. Try `SwankyandMooMoo` or  `Swanky and Moo Moo`.