# Custom font issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, fonts, uifont

I added "kaligraf_latin.ttf" to "Fonts provided by application" in the info.plist

Then I use `UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"kaligraf_latin" size:17]` and font = nil

I tried kaligraf_latin.otf. The result is the same.

Then I tried another font MyriadPro-BoldCond.otf, and font becomes != nil.

Does it mean, that the problem is in the font kaligraf_latin.ttf?

Here is printscreen of info.plist
[image]

May be the problem is in the name of the font. Because in fontWithName I should use font name, not font file name. How can I get font name from font file?

Comment: you should use font name not file name

Comment: you have to add the custom font file into your application.....

Comment: Refer my following link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355985/swanky-and-moo-moo-font-is-not-working-in-ios Hope it will helps you....

Comment: How can I get font name from font file?

Comment: Add this font to your Font Book (OS X application), select this font in the list, and press Command+I, you will see font information, check if you use in application correct PostScript name.

Comment: Are you using the correct name of the custom font?

Comment: try setting the font name with capital letters

Answer (score 4):

Using the following two methods you can check if custom fonts or also the sub fonts are installed

```
[UIFont familyNames];
[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:<font family name>];
```

hope it will help you a little.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to list all the font available (include the one you add) and there font name :

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
{
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
    fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                 [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                  [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
    for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
    {
        NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the font name
It was Kaligraf Latin, not kaligraf_latin
I got font name using this website http://www.font2web.com/