# How to use Custom font in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

In my application i want to use `Futura Heavy BT` font but as i checked the supported font on this page for [iOS6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484) and [iOS7](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5878) and `Futura Heavy BT` so is there any way to use this font or i have to use any alternative?

Comment: You can use custom fonts, see this [post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names

Comment: you have font files?  see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355985/swanky-and-moo-moo-font-is-not-working-in-ios/14356123#14356123

Comment: Please be aware that you need to have the permission to re-distribute the custom font you include with your application, that may be included with a license you get if you purchase the font, or if the font is public domain that is not an issue.  I'm not sure Futura Heavy BT is a free font though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add custom fonts if its not available in the list that Apple provides. A very good [tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) to learn how to use custom fonts in iOS.

Comment: But its want `OTF` file and i have `LWFN` file

Comment: You can download the font from here. http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Futura-Heavy/

Comment: Parcs That link does not give the futura heavy font

Comment: I have uploaded the font file to my dropbox shared folder, you can download it from there. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75143596/futura_heavy.ttf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42106/discussion-between-parcs-and-dilip)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the custom font in iOS app follow the steps:

Download the font .ttf etc.

Copy it in your project.

Goto info.plist and add new property than search for "Fonts provided by application" and add the font names.

Than goto your viewcontroller and

`NSLog(@"Font names: %@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Futura"]);`

From console copy the font name and use it.

```
[UIFont fontWithName:fontname size:15.0f];
```